# Why isn't this regex working in python? It's valid and works fine on RegExr

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have this regex with I'm using to split a string into tokens I can process later. I made it using RegExr (online tool) and it works fine there, but I can't get it to work in python. I'm using this now to print the matches.

```
sunit = "A^2.1e2 m/s -180.2"
pat = "[A-Za-z]+(\^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)?|\/|\*|[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?"
Terms = re.findall(pat,sunit)
print Terms
```

The regex should be matching:

```
A^2.1e2
m
/
s
-180.2
```

Comment: Get in the habit of using raw string literals when defining regexes: not "\.*" but r"\.*".  Using raw string literals (with the leading 'r' character), you don't have to double up the backslashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it. Using 're.finditer()' instead of 're.findall()' seems to work. Here is what I came up with now. Sorry for bothering you, I should have been able solved this a long time ago.

```
sunit = r"A^2.1e2 m/s -180.2"
pat = r"[A-Za-z]+(\^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)?|\/|\*|[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?"
Terms = re.finditer(pat,sunit)
for m in Terms:
    print m.group(0)
```

Comment: What bothers me is that more people don't come back and post their solutions as you just did. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have group captures `(...)` in your regex. If you do not wish to capture the groups, then just remove the brackets from there. Or use `?:` inside the bracket to ignore it, example `(?:...)`. I have changed your regex and it will work with `re.findall`

```
pat = "[A-Za-z]+(?:\^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)?|\/|\*|[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?"
                 ^^                       ^^                                               ^^
```